# When exactly does a PendingIntent get disposed/removed?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am using a `PendingIntent` along with `AlarmManager` and a `BroadcastReceiver` to show reminders at a user specified time. I am displaying the reminder using the `NotificationManager`.

Before a notification is set, I want a button to say **"Set Reminder"** and after the notification is set I want the button to say **"Change Reminder"**. As soon as the notification is shown to the user, the button should again say **"Set Reminder"**.

I am creating the same `PendingIntent` with the same intent, context and the same unique id (myUniqueId) to check whether the `PendingIntent` is active.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderReceiver.class);
boolean reminderActive = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, myUniqueId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

Now this works and the button text is displayed properly. But I figured out that as soon as the notification is shown, unless I explicitly retrieves the same `PendingIntent` and cancels it, it's **NOT** removed for a while. So for sometime, the button still says "Change Reminder".

So is it correct to assume that unless I explicitly cancels the PendingIntent it's still stored somewhere in the memory to be garbage collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it correct to assume that unless I explicitly cancels the PendingIntent it's still stored somewhere in the memory

Yes. Android caches `PendingIntent` objects. AFAIK, they will hang around until the process is terminated.